# Converting function based view to class based view to return JSON Response

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a function based view which works fine with Bootstrap Modal dialog and returns the JSON Response. I am trying to implement this with `CreateView` but couldn't make it to work.

**Function Based View which works fine :-**

```
def task_create(request):
    form = CreateTaskForm(initial={'owner' : request.user,
                               'assignee' :  request.user})
    context = {'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('tasks/task_create_ajax.html',
        context,
        request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

**Attempt for Class Based View :-**

```
class CreateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   form_class = CreateTaskForm

   def get_template_names(self):
      if self.request.is_ajax():
        return ['tasks/task_create_ajax.html']
      else:
        return ['tasks/createtask.html']

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(CreateTaskView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs.update({'initial': {'owner' : self.request.user,
                               'assignee' : self.request.user}})
      return kwargs

   def form_invalid(self, form):
     response = super(CreateTaskView,self).form_invalid(form)
     if self.request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
     else:
        return response

   def form_valid(self, form):
     response = super(CreateTaskView, self).form_valid(form)
     if self.request.is_ajax():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        data = {
            'message': "Successfully submitted form data."
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
     else:
        return response
```

**Problem :-**

In function based view, the html form is passed via variable `html_form` which I can view/debug in browser using `console.dump` command. When I use the class based view, my form didn't get populated.

Can someone please suggest what should be the correct approach to make it work with class based view? How can I pass the `JsonResponse` for the form (get method) with `CreateView`?

Comment: Why do you use CBV for that? They are used especially for repeated views so that thay can be inherited and should follow DRY. But I don't see any purpose of having that specific view in CBV. If you really need, have a look at Django Rest Framework which is used to it.

Comment: I wanted to use Bootstrap Modal dialogs and my class based views are already working without this requirement. So, I thought if I can extend my CBV to be used with Bootstrap Modals as well.

Comment: It looks like that FBV is much more simpler and better for that in my oppinion. Else you will have to override more than one (even two) methods and that is ugly and long.

Comment: Can you please provide any pointers about what all methods needs to be overriden? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the doc about [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#jsonresponsemixin-example)?